# play framework downloading file

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

I am new in play framework I want download a file in the following way:

- brought the file path from the database.
- click on the path should open a file in a web form.

Is it possible to do in play framework?if yes how to think about give me some idea please..

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Downloading a file can be done easily using play controller as follows,

```
public Result downloadFile(){
    File fileToDownload = new File("/path/fileToDownload.pdf"):

    response().setContentType("application/x-download");
    response().setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=fileToDownload.pdf");

    return ok(fileToDownload);
}
```

**The Scala Way**

```
def downloadFile = Action {
  Ok.sendFile(
  content = new java.io.File("/path/fileToDownload.pdf"),
  fileName = _ => "fileToDownload.pdf"
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you mean the file path on the server, then this is trivial. Just use the `renderBinary` method. This can take an input stream or a File object, so ...

```
renderBinary(new File(filepath));
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

an example

in model with JPA

```
@Lob
@Column(name="NY_FILE",length=100000, nullable=false)
private byte[] myFile;

@Column(name="MIME_TYPE", nullable=false)
private String mimeType;
```

Controller

```
@play.db.jpa.Transactional(readOnly=true)
public Result download(Long id){
    myPOJO = arquivo.findByid(JPAapi.em(), id);
    return ok(MyPOJO.getMyFile()).as(myPOJO.getMimeType());
}
```

routes file

```
GET     /download/:id   @controllers.MyController.download(id:Long)
```

HTML link

```
<a id="linkDownload" href="/download/@myPOJO.getMyFile.getId" target="_blank">
   @myPOJO.getMyFile.getName
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
File file = new File("file pathfr");
return ok(file);
```

Comment: Please consider adding some sort of explanation with your solution, that way everyone can learn from you!